# Create thumbnail from .flv and .swf files in android

Tags: android, video-capture

I need to create the thumbnail of .flv and .swf files on android. Searched on google and most of the links suggested about using xuggler but I am not able to find any simple tutorial. Are there gudies on how to do this?

Comment: have u seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345085/how-to-create-only-one-thumbnail-from-flash-video-with-xuggler

Comment: I saw that page but not able to understand that clearly. In that its mentioned to use xuggler but am unable to download the media tool api. all the links i found is broken